# How to implement pay to remove ads in React Native (iOS and Android)

Tags: react-native, admob, applepay, google-pay

Hi I have a react native app with ads using `react-native-admob` I want the user to be able to click and pay to remove the ads. Please how do I go about doing this on both iOS and Android? I also want to ensure that when the user updates the app, they do not get the version with ads if they had previously bought the app.
Any ideas or libraries to use will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a package for in-app purchases such as [react-native-iap](https://github.com/dooboolab/react-native-iap). There are methods for buying products which you would set up in your Google Play and App Store dashboards. As for keeping track of which users have already paid for what products, that is [mentioned in the docs](https://github.com/dooboolab/react-native-iap#consumption-and-restoring-purchases).